# Eclipse rcp extension cannot be found in registry

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I am developing an Eclipse e4 RCP application. As an example, there are two plugins `A` and `B`. `A` is set up as the application plugin in product definition. It defines an extension point `EP` that needs contribution from plugin `B`. The start page, defined in `A`, of the application contains some widgets requiring extension of `EP` by `B` to set up. The problem is that the extension by `B` is not available while constructing the start page. I did some debugging, and found `EP` could be acquired from the registry. However, `EP.getExtensions()` returns empty array. I thought that could be caused by plugin's lazy loading. So I tried to set plugin's start level and auto load. It didn't work. Then I tried to define an extension of `org.eclipse.ui.startup`. It didn't help either. I have run out all solutions I could imagine. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This does not sound like an e4 application (were you can't use 'org.eclipse.ui.startup' or an application plugin). What do you mean by 'start page'? Is this something being displayed before the main application window?

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for the response. "Start page" means the application main page which is the page loaded after the application is started. "Application plugin" is the one selected in the product definition in the "Product" field. The idea is that the main page (or so called start page) needs to get all the extensions for certain extension point to set up the page accordingly. As what I can see in OSGi console, the plugin providing the extension is not loaded no matter what I do. Hope this help you understand the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem. I ran the application using the Run button on Eclipse's toolbar. The run command was initially created when the application was started in the product definition editor. The plugin was added after the first run, and it did not get updated to the run command for the button on toolbar. I manually removed the command from the run button and rerun the app from product definition editor. Everything works fine now.